# Loop opening a spreadsheet, and copying from sheet a to sheet b

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just don't understand where the problem is,

must be super simple but this does not work.

Sorry for the newbee question.

```
function GoGetData() {
var ss =  
SpreadsheetApp.openById("1tyfIzGNDZr4JK9kYwABDMLBvK7B3jJ4r2wQfMOIPd3I");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('List des dossiers du Folder') // Sheet=liste des dossiers

for(var i=1; i>3; i++) 
{      
Logger.log(i);



var IdShpread = sheet.getRange(i,2,1,1); // va prender l,adresse de La sheet

var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(IdShpread); // open la sheet avec les data

var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('regroup');

var targetsheet = source.getSheetByName('worksheet');

// Copy de l'ensemble de la Sheet
var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange("A1:L1000").copyTo(targetsheet.getRange("A1:L1000"), {contentsOnly: true});

  //pour copier seulement certaines parties a netraliser apres
  //var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange("D7:K7").copyTo(targetsheet.getRange("D7:K7"), {contentsOnly: true});
}
}
```

Comment: The `i>3` in the for loop is a problem.

Comment: yes...ok, Shame does not kill. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the sheet Ids, which are located in the cells of your range, you need to use the method [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). Modify your script as following:

```
function GoGetData() {
var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1tyfIzGNDZr4JK9kYwABDMLBvK7B3jJ4r2wQfMOIPd3I");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('List des dossiers du Folder') // Sheet=liste des dossiers
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {      
 var IdShpread = sheet.getRange(i,2,1,1).getValue(); // va prender l,adresse de La sheet
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(IdShpread); // open la sheet avec les data
 var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('regroup');
 var targetsheet = source.getSheetByName('worksheet');
 sourcesheet.getRange("A1:L1000").copyTo(targetsheet.getRange("A1:L1000"), {contentsOnly: true});
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function GoGetData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1tyfIzGNDZr4JK9kYwABDMLBvK7B3jJ4r2wQfMOIPd3I");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('List des dossiers du Folder');
  for(var i=1;i<3;i++) {      
    Logger.log(i);
    var IdShpread=sh.getRange(i,2,1,1);
    var source=SpreadsheetApp.openById(IdShpread);
    var sourcesheet=source.getSheetByName('regroup');
    var targetsheet=source.getSheetByName('worksheet');
    sourcesheet.getRange("A1:L1000").copyTo(targetsheet.getRange("A1:L1000"), {contentsOnly: true});
  }
}
```

Comment: How this answer the question?

Comment: You could explain why the OP code isn't working, and/or what your code does and why it works, and/or what changes you made to the OP code...